# What's the origin of the common phrase "I call shenanigans"?

Tags: etymology, idioms

What's the origin of the common phrase "I call shenanigans"? Note that I'm not so much looking for the origin of *shenanigans* itself, which I expect could easily be found in the OED or something, but when the entire phrase took on a life of its own as an independent construction.   Who coined it? When was it first attested? Did anyone make it particular popular?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've got a use of "call shenanigans" that dates to 1998, and I strongly suspect that, even if it isn't the *earliest* use, it's the source of the phrase's popularity over the last decade or so.

In "[Cow Days](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cow_Days)," the thirteenth episode of the second season of *South Park*, the boys are at a carnival playing games which they come to suspect are rigged. Kyle calls shenanigans, which brings Officer Barbrady to investigate. However, the carny allows the boys to win the game when the officer is present, and Kyle retracts his call of shenanigans.

Later in the episode, the boys discover that the prizes they were trying to win are in fact cheap knock-offs, and Kyle formally reinstates his claim of shenanigans. The claim is upheld this time by Officer Barbrady, which gives the townspeople free rein to destroy the carnival with brooms.

Again, this may not be the very first use of the term, but you asked whether anyone had made it particularly popular, and I think this is what did it. I saw the episode when it was new, and I remember quite distinctly thinking that I'd never heard the word *shenanigans* used that way before—but within days of the airing of that episode, several of my friends were calling shenanigans every chance they got.

Comment: I suspect "call shenanigans" is just a quirky variant of [cry foul](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/cry-foul). Whether it "existed" before the South Park usage may be somewhat irrelevant, since that would almost certainly be where it started to gain traction.

Comment: This should mention that "Cow Days" was 1998 (and thus before the citation from 2000), but I couldn't find a graceful way to edit it in.

Answer (score 4):

The earliest citation from a quick Lexis-Nexis search reveals this one from the 4 Feb 2000 edition of the *Lincoln Journal Star*:

> "I call this shenanigans," Sen. Ed Schrock of Elm Creek said of the opponents' amendment to LB701.

I realize that you're looking for the specific phrase "I call shenanigans", but if you relax your criteria somewhat, you can go back even further.  For example, according to an anthology of Mark Twain's letters published in 1920, he once wrote:

> Consider them all..guilty (of ‘shenanigan’) until they are proved innocent.

Which is a somewhat more verbose way of calling shenanigans.

And even further back, the San Francisco daily newspaper *Spirit of Age* wrote the following in their 30 April 1856 issue:

> These facts indicate that there is some shenanegan [sic] going on.

As with almost every turn of phrase, the spoken origins probably far predate anything written.

Comment: the top answer is South Park? :S

Comment: @ioSamurai South Park reintroduced the term (which was dated had fallen out of use) to the consciousness of the international public via this exact phrase, now immortalised as a satirical pop culture trope.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a use of "call [or declare or claim] shenanigans" earlier than *2002* , but in the March 1990 issue of *Spin* magazine, Julian Dibbell wrote (emphasis added):

> And why wouldn't the media *call
>   bullshit* on corporate claims of huge
>   losses to the computer underground?

Sometime in the 90s, apparently, someone substituted a harmless word and the rest is forgotten history...

Comment: I believe there's a connection to the card game politely known as "I doubt it".

Comment: @DavidSchwartz; more probably Liar Dice, but I love the idea of *Who's for a game of 'I doubt it'?*

Comment: I think "call bullshit" is probably just an Americanisation of British "cry foul", as commented under Nicholas's answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I don't think so; they mean slighly different things.

Comment: @T.E.D.: Well, you've put that out there. What do *you* think the different meanings are?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - "call BS" is not letting a statement you consider untrue slide without complaint. "call foul" is not letting an occurrance you consider an injustice (typically against yourself) slide without complaint. I don't disagree with your comment on the other answer, but calling "shenanegans" and "BS" are two different things. At least that's my understanding from this side of the pond...

Comment: @T.E.D.: Personally, I would never use either "call bullshit" or "call shenanigans". But so far as I'm concerned, "cry foul" is used in both of your contexts, and "call shenanigans" just means the speaker watches South Park (or maybe his friends do).

Comment: @T.E.D. at least in American English, the *referee* "calls" a foul (i.e., he acts with authority); any player can "cry" foul (i.e. complain to the ref, or the spectators).  When you say you are "calling shenanigans", it certainly sounds to me like you making a purportedly authoritative judgment.