# Synonym for "call bulls--t"

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests, synonyms, offensive-language

I am writing a column for publication in a widely circulated newspaper, and would like to use a phrase meaning something like "call bullshit". I can't think of one that captures the [meaning](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=I%20call%20bullshit) so succinctly. I certainly don't want to use the original phrase (not my style, and it's partly aimed at school students of varying ages).

To aid in finding options, the intended excerpt is something like:

> If you claim to have compiled such a list then I know I can always call bullshit by finding an item you missed.

NB: the deception was not intentional on the part of the list compiler — they *missed* an item, not omitted it.

Comment: In that case, you could use "such a careless person!"

Comment: In that case *calling bullshit* is not appropriate in the first place.  That implies either a willful intent to deceive or complete ignorance.

Comment: @Jim - I'm leaning towards the implication of complete ignorance. But perhaps my internalised meaning of the phrase is incorrect!

Comment: Someone is bullshitting when they try to talk as if they are an expert about things of which they know very little.  When someone realizes that they are doing this they can call that person a bullshitter and what they're saying bullshit.  But it all stems from trying to deceive the listener into believing they know more than they actually do.  The phrase has been extended to include lying in general- you can call someone's blatant lie *bullshit* as well.

Comment: Ah, ok. Then this (or synonyms) is not the phrase I'm looking for. Though the meaning is not far off, I think I'll search for an easier phrase to use.

Comment: I would just call your list *less than complete* or *far from complete*

Comment: @Jim - not strong enough, I'm afraid. There's a sense of "you're just not getting it; it will never be complete!" but as I said, I'll try for something else.

Comment: It sounds like you're thinking of the word *incompetent* in your own language.

Comment: How about *attempting to compile such a list is a fool's errand*

Comment: My own language is English :-)

Comment: Oops, I'm very sorry!

Comment: @DamkerngT. - no worries, I didn't specify I was a native speaker.

Comment: @DamkerngT. - more like well-meaning, but not understanding the subtleties of the attempted task.

Comment: If so, a few words come to my mind: *innocent*, *naive*, *childish*, *silly* (I think it's a bit softer than *fool* or *stupid*.)

Comment: "I call inept" might work.

Answer (score 2):

This may be inadequate for your purposes, but to "call foul" is equivalent.

Comment: I seem to have somehow missed the comments below your question. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

My vote would go to "I call shenanigans," a fairly recent expression that may very well have its origin in euphemism, as Malvolio suggests in an answer to the question [What's the origin of the common phrase "I call shenanigans"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20626/whats-the-origin-of-the-common-phrase-i-call-shenanigans) —asked on this site back in April 2011.

The two-word phrase "call shenanigans" yields no matches in a Google Books search through the year 2008, but a standard exact-phrase search for "I call shenanigans" on Google produces more than 1.8 million matches, so it's clearly a popular phrase.

Answer (score -2):

How about

> If you claim to have compiled such a list then I know I can always
>   **[spot Waldo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where%27s_Wally?)** by finding an item you missed.

Works for me.

Comment: To me (not an American) that seems like a very weird phrase, even after translating it to 'spot Wally'. It would be almost meaningless in my country, I think.

Comment: @user58312 So make it mean something in your country.

Comment: @Mr_Spock hardly a useful expression for the present if it's not intuitive **and** not known. So it's understandably not useful to the OP. I appreciate your principle, though.